# varargs to map in Kotlin

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, kotlin

I use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in my project and pass parameters this way:

```
MapSqlParameterSource(mapOf(
    "userId" to userId,
    "count" to count
))
```

I don't want to write the first line all the time and I want to create my own function that will take pairs of string-to-any values:

```
params(
    "userId" to userId,
    "count" to count
)
```

But when I try to implement it I have issues with generics (I don't post the error description here):

```
fun params(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any>) = MapSqlParameterSource(mapOf(pairs))
```

Could you please advice on the correct implementation?

Comment: Why don't you post the error message? It helps people to see the problem without having to try it out themselves...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mapOf` has 3 implementations: taking nothing, taking 1 pair and taking a vararg of pairs.

Since `pairs` in your code is actually `Array<Pair<String, Any>>` there is no matching implementation of `mapOf` to call. This is due to the fact that varargs as java implements them are ambiguous in certain cases so Kotlin requires explicit arguments.

To make it work use the "spread" operator to indicate the vararg method should be used. (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

`fun params(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any>) = MapSqlParameterSource(mapOf(*pairs))`

Comment: Beware, that `mapOf(*pairs)` creates a copy of `pairs` array before passing it to `mapOf`. It might be better to use `pairs.toMap()`